# Navigate in code with react-router-dom 4.0?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

Looking at [this video](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) the react router seems easy to use, but I can't find how to navigate in my code since I want to link on clicking a div and not use `<Link>`.

I've search StackOverflow but haven't found any answers that work with 4.0.  Trying to import browserHistory gives undefined (before and after installing 'react-router' in addition to 'react-router-dom') from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router):

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
console.log('browserHistory:', browserHistory);
```

I also saw somewhere that there is a 'context' you can get to, but this shows a value for 'match' but not 'context':

```
<Route path="/" render={({ match, context}) => {
    console.log('match:', match);
    console.log('context:', context);
```

***Edit***

In the dev tools I can see that "Router" has a history property, so when I add that I can get to it:

```
<Route path="/" render={({ match, context, history}) => {
```

Is there a way to get to this from outside a route?  For example a navbar component that will navigate to other components, but is not inside a Route itself...

Comment: initialize your own history and call history.push https://www.npmjs.com/package/history, also dont forget to use this history in your <Router>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to read into the docs more.  The `history` object is only passed as a property using the `component` (or other) attributes on a `Route`.  Apparently need to include the 'history' package and use `createBrowserHistory` and pass it to the `Router`, then specify the component in a `Route`.  I think this should work fine since `exact` isn't specified...

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
ReactDOM.render( (
    <Router history={ history }>
      <Route path="/" component={ App } />
    </Router>
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Before I just had `<App/>` inside `<Router>` and didn't have access to those properties.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, this is how you make a link programaticaly.

```
    class Test extends React.Component {

      handleClick() {
        console.log(this.context);
        this.context.router.history.push('/some/path');
      },

      render() {

        return (
          <div onClick={handleClick}>
            This is div.
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    Test.contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Test />,
      document.getElementById("app")
    );
```

Comment: Where does 'context' come from?  I don't see it in the react dev tools on my 'App' component, but when I log it I see an empty object in the console.

Comment: Hmmm...  `this.context` is undefined  for me...  Does the component have to be inside a `<Route>` or something?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat this.context is set by adding contextTypes to the component: 
`Test.contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap your div in the link instead of trying to circumvent it and make your life easier?

```
    <Link to="/" >
       <div className="to-component">go to component</div>
    </Link>
```

Comment: This does seem to be the easiest solution to the problem, I came here with the same issue.  I'm wondering if there is a downside to using this method.